# jQuery - Get the absolute path from URL string containing "../"

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I don't know if it is answered already before. I don't know what to search for.

All I want to know is if there is a jquery function for the following problem.

Let's say I have an URL string like this - `www.example.com/a/b/../c`
I want to get `www.example.com/a/c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way is to create a link element, set its `href` property, and then read it.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://www.example.com/a/b/../c";
var resolved = a.href;
console.log(resolved); // "http://www.example.com/a/c"
```

Or using some jQuery:

```
var resolved = $("<a>").prop("href", "http://www.example.com/a/b/../c").prop("href");
console.log(resolved); // "http://www.example.com/a/c"
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/kamifeci/1)

This works relative to the current document's path, although with the URL above it doesn't matter as the URL is absolute.

Note that it's important that we're using the reflected property, not the attribute, here.

Comment: This is actually amazing! Never thought about it! Awesome! Thank you very much!